# How to disable factory reset button for Company owned Device in Android Management API?

Tags: android-management-api, android-work-profile

I am setting Factory Reset Protection (FRP) for COMPANY-OWNED device with WORK PROFILE. Such that, user can only bypass using FRP email.

Though It works well when the device is hard reset but when the user does the same through

> Settings -> Backup & Reset -> Erase All Data

, it doesn't ask for FRP on startup.

So, What I'm trying to achieve is disable the factory reset button in settings for COMPANY-OWNED WORK PROFILE devices, so that the user doesn't bypass the FRP.

I have tried to patch the device with the policy with

`"factoryResetDisabled": true,`

[source](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies)

but it doesn't reflect in the device.

Kindly suggest me other ways, for Work Profile in Android Management API.
Is any workaround available to disable the Factory Reset Button?

[image: I want to Disable 'Erase All Data' button]

Answer (score 0):

Factory Reset Prevention (factoryResetDisabled) api does not work on COMPANY-OWNED devices with WORK PROFILE as of android 11 onwards. Since factory resetting is the only reliable way to remove all user data from COPE devices or COMPANY-OWNED devices with WORK PROFILE.